# Minecraft crashed after I coded the splash screen

Tags: minecraft

Every time I launch Minecraft this happens, this error started when I coded in the splash screen and I don't know where I went wrong with the code[enter link description here](https://pastebin.pl/view/7c83c432)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try uninstalling Java SE Runtime Environment an re-installing it? You could also try doing the same for the Minecraft Launcher?

(I'm not 100% sure this will work.)